# How to label test data using trained model with keras?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working on the following keras convolutional neural network tutorial https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d

After training the model I want to test the model on sample images, and also label the images. I realize that I have to use [predict](https://keras.io/models/model/) method that generates an array that shows which label gets what score for a particular image. But I am having trouble using this method. If the images are in the folder *test_images* and there are 20 of them, how do I test these images and get the prediction?

This is how I've gotten with one image (even though I want it for multiple images):

```
image = cv2.imread('test1.jpg')
image = cv2.resize(image,(224,224))
features = np.swapaxes(np.swapaxes(image, 1, 2), 0, 1)
predictions = model.predict(features)
```

This throws the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking : expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (3, 224, 224)
```

Thank you very much!

Some of the questions I consulted before:

[Simple Neural Network in Python not displaying label for the test image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319055/simple-neural-network-in-python-not-displaying-label-for-the-test-image)
https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/315

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model.predict` works by processing an array of samples, not just one image, so you are missing the batch/samples dimension, which in your case would only be just one image. You just have to reshape the array:

```
features = features.reshape((1, 3, 224, 224)
```

And then pass it to predict.

Comment: Great! It worked for one image. I deleted the swapaxes part and added the line you advised. For this tutorial I had to resize it to (150,150). Could you please add to your answer how I can use it for multiples images, say 20 images? Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I got it.